# How to print a canvas element AND another element to same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, printing

I'm trying to print a canvas element, along with a heading element, to a page.
I need the heading element on the page to define the canvas element-turned-image. 
Here's my code:

```
<script>
    $(function print(){

        function print_content(){
            canvas = document.getElementById('exerciseChart');
            printHeading = document.getElementById('headingOne');
            var win=window.open();
            win.document.write("<br><img src='"+canvas.toDataURL()+"'/>");
            win.document.write("<br><img src='"+printHeading.toDataURL()+"'/>");
            win.print();
            win.location.reload();
        }

        $("#printContent").click(function(){ print_content(); });

    }); // end $(function(){});
</script>
```

The code I'm using (borrowed from StackOverflow) to print the canvas element (`exerciseChart`) alone works great. When I try to print the heading element (`headingOn`e) along with the canvas element, nothing happens.

This may seem like a basic question, but it's a problem I've been battling for some time now. Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: What type of element is `#headingOne` ? I this an HTMLCanvasElement ? If not, it won't have a `toDataURL()` method.

Comment: "headingOne" is an h3 element. looks like     <h3 id='headingOne' align="center" > Resistance Exercise Reports </h3>

Answer (score 0):

Could you pls try `innerHtml` and html tags in new window. Try something like this;

```
canvas = document.getElementById('exerciseChart');
printHeading = document.getElementById('headingOne');
var win=window.open('', '', 'height=500,width=900');
win.document.write('<html><head><title>Lets print</title>');            
win.document.write('<head/><body>');
win.document.write(canvas.innerHTML);
win.document.write(printHeading.innerHTML);
win.document.write('</body></html>');
```